# Unable to update Git fork due to "unrelated history"

Tags: git

My company has a fork of the [SDL repository](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL), which was last updated to the version `2.0.10` (around 4 years ago). I would like to update our fork to the version `2.28.0` (currently the latest SDL version). We have around 20 of our own commits that we need to keep.

In order to do this, I added the official repository as a remote called `upstream`. Then, I attempted to merge the `upstream` tag `2.28.0` into our fork, but got the error `refusing to merge unrelated histories`.

When comparing the same commits from both repositories, I noticed that they have different hashes. I don't know how this happened; maybe one of the repositories had its history rewritten? Because of this, both repositories are identical when checking out the `2.0.10` tag, however, Git thinks they are completely different.

I'd like to be able to merge `upstream` into our fork. Is there a way to tell Git that both repositories share the same history? For example, would it be possible to replace our fork's history with `upstream`'s history up to the version `2.0.10` commit? Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: I assume the reason you have a fork is that your company has done local changes to it and that is why history has been re-written, or? If you need those changes maybe you could save them somewhere say in a patch, then reset the history to the last common ancestor, merge master from upstream and then re-apply back your local changes again (likely a few merge conflicts over 4 years though)?

Comment: @firmament Yeah, we have some local changes, but they're just normal commits, so I'm not sure why the history is different. After Googling a bit, I found out that [SDL switched to GitHub in 2021](https://discourse.libsdl.org/t/sdl-moving-to-github/28700), so maybe that could have caused history issues.

But yeah, your suggestion sounds doable. I'd say we have around 20 local commits, so it's manageable. I'll check tomorrow if it can be done with patches.

Comment: Use `git merge --allow-unrelated-histories` for the first time.